# Average datetime.time Series

Tags: pandas, datetime, time

I am trying to figure out the best way to average a series of `datetime.time` values with about 40 records in the format of `23:19:30` or `HH:MM:SS`, however, when I attempt to use the `to_timedelta` method and apply `.mean()` I run into an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>
```

What would be the proper format for the time to be in to use `to_timedelta().mean()` or is there a better approach?

Code:

```
bed_time_mean = pd.to_timedelta(bed_rise_df['start_time']).mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_timedelta` accepts strings in H:M:S format as input, so you could convert your column with datetime.time objects to string first. Ex:

```
from datetime import time
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'t':[time(1,2,3), time(2,3,4), time(3,4,5)]})

pd.to_timedelta(df['t'].astype(str)).mean()
# Timedelta('0 days 02:03:04')
```